# Designing an app to be deployed with AND without Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-datastore

After I finish developing an app using Google App Engine, how easy will it be to distribute if  I ever need to do so without App Engine? The only thing I've thought of is that GAE has some proprietary API for using the datastore. So, if I need to deliver my app as a .war file (for example) which would not be deployed with App Engine, all I would need to do is first refactor any code which is getting/storing data, before building the .war, right?

I don't know what the standard way is to deliver a finished web app product - I've only ever used GAE, but I'm starting a project now for which the requirements for final deliverables are unsure at this time.

So I'm wondering, if I develop for GAE, how easy will it be to convert?

Also, is there anything I can do or consider while writing for GAE to optimize the project for whatever packaging options I may have in the end?

Answer (score 1):

So long as your app does not have any elements that are dependent of Google App engines you should be able to deploy anywhere so long as the location can support a Tomcat or GlassFish server. Sometimes this requires that you manually install the server so you must read up on that. There are lots of youtubes that help on this subject just try to break down your issue to the lowest steps possible.

I also suggest using a framework like spring and hibernate to help lessen the headaches. They will take a while to understand but are worth the headache if you want to be programming for the rest of your life.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Pbrain19.

The GAE datastore is quite different from SQL, and has its own interesting eventually consistent behavior for transactions.  That means for anything that requires strong consistency or transactions, you're going to have to structure your data with appropriate ancestors.  This is going to have a pretty big impact on your code.

You're also going to need to denormalize your data structures (compared to SQL) to minimize datastore costs and improve performance.  There's also many queries you can do in SQL that you can't do in GAE, you'd have to structure your app in ways to work around this.

Once you do any of this, you'll probably have a significant chunk of the app to rebuild.

You also wouldn't want to use Spring because it'll make your instance start up time pretty painful.

So unless it's a very simple hello world app, the refactoring will not be trivial - particularly once you begin using ancestors in any of your data modelling.

I recommend not trying to design your app to be portable if you're using the GAE datastore.

You'll have better luck making a portable app if you're using  Cloud SQL.